# VirtualBox with Windows 7 No Sound

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, audio

I've tried to search for solution to this, 
I've upgraded to the latest version of VirtualBox (3.2.6) 
I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx. 
I've installed Windows 7, and it detects a 
"Multimedia Audio Controller" (you gotta love those amazing descriptions) 
How do I make it detect that controller?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are running Windows 7 as the guest OS, because it's not very clear from your question. You need to select Windows DirectSound and ICH AC97 as the Audio controller in the VM's Audio settings, and then you have to install the [Realtek AC97 Drivers](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=23&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#AC) from Realtek's website.

[Here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14155) is a thread on the Virtualbox forums with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Windows 7 guest on Ubuntu 10.04 host:

from [VirtualBox Website](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=32322&hilit=sound)

In Control Panel - System and security - Windows Update:
On the left side, manually select 'Check for Updates'.

Under 'Optional Updates', will be a 'Recommended' item, 
'Microsoft Driver Update for Intel(r) 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller'.

Select this from the list, and install it.

After this, the sound was skipping. this was fixed by unselecting the "Enable Nested Paging"

```
settings > system > acceleration > enable nested paging
```

Good Luck!